# How treat data with Firebase and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm trying building an App with AngularJS and Firebase - any one have tried?
I'm following [this](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire) and using the fist method (implicit sync.) to synchronise my models with Firebase. 
In my app I want to have two db/json files (Firebase Url) (kind of stuff) one for users and one for votes.

So I did :

```javascript
var url = 'mypath.firebaseio.com/votes';
var promise = angularFire(url, $scope, 'votes', []);

promise.then(function() {
  $scope.removeVotes = function() { 
    $scope.votes.splice($scope.toRemove, 1); 
    $scope.toRemove = null;
  };
});

//then I push my votes with a function
$scope.addVote = function() {
  $scope.votes.push({
    from:user.username, 
    to:$scope.voteTo, 
    motivation:$scope.voteMotivation, date:today 
  });
};
```

and this works fine I can see my votes in the html rendered with my

```xml
<li ng-repeat="vote in votes">
```

ok
so I did same thing for users:

```javascript
var url1 = 'mypath.firebaseio.com/users';
var promise1 = angularFire(url1, $scope, 'users', []);

promise1.then(function() {
  $scope.users.push({
    name: user.username, 
    pic: user.profile_image_url
  });
  $scope.removeUser = function() {
    $scope.users.splice($scope.toRemove, 1);
    $scope.toRemove = null;
  };
});
```

Now I can see my users rendered in my html markup with

```xml
<li ng-repeat="user in users">
```

but that s no trace of my data at https://alex-jpcreative.firebaseio.com/users

Any ideas why?

Comment: hello @Alex, i m also trying to build basic app on angular-firebase.
but i got problem while deleting json object. for ex. let's say in ur above code $scope.users.splice($scope.toRemove, 1); this statement will remove data from frontend but is it also delete same record from firebase ? if yes then here is my question please help me to figure out this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954639/how-to-delete-json-data-object-in-firebase-using-angular

Comment: In the code you have 'mypath.firebaseio.com', but you're checking 'alex-jpcreative.firebaseio.com' - are you sure you're seeing the same URL in both places?

Comment: how don't remember how but I solve this out - thanks