# how to delete json data object in firebase using angular?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have developed simple angular-firebase application which provide basic CRUD functionality.

json format in firebase

```
{
  "-J0wuZ_J8P1EO5g4Xfw6" : {
    "contact" : "56231545",
    "company" : "info",
    "city" : "limbdi",
    "name" : "priya"
  },
  "-J0wrhrtgFvIdyMcSL0x" : {
    "contact" : "65325422",
    "company" : "rilance",
    "city" : "jamnagar",
    "name" : "pihu"
  }
}
```

angular-code for listing all data in html page

```
<table class='table table-hover'>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="item in employee">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.city}}</td>
        <td>{{item.company}}</td>
        <td>{{item.contact}}</td>
        <td><button class='btn btn-warning btn-mini' ng-click='delemp(employee[$index])'>X</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

when someone click on button it fire delemp function which take employee's current index as argument.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp',['firebase']);
myapp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'angularFireCollection',
  function MyCtrl($scope, angularFireCollection) {

       $scope.delemp=function($current_emp){
          alert($current_emp.name);
    };
  }
]);
```

this alert box contain current employee's name. I want to delete current row of employee. but I don't know how to use `remove()` method of firebase. I have visited documentation of firebase so I got bellow code which is working nice.

```
var current = new Firebase('https://myurl/employee/-J48go0dwY5M3jAC34Op');
        current.onDisconnect().remove();
```

but I want to make it dynamically so how can I get parent id of current node like `-J48go0dwY5M3jAC34Op`  ?

please help me to figure out small issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

instead of passing the object, you could just pass the id into your delete function.

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,item) in list">
  <button ng-click="deleteItem(key)">delete</button> {{item.name}} 
</li>

$scope.deleteItem = function(id){
  var itemRef = new Firebase(url + '/' + id);
  itemRef.remove();
}
```

edit:
this also works

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
    <button ng-click="writeID(item)">log id</button>{{item.$id}} {{item}}<hr>
</div>

$scope.writeID = function(o){
  console.log(o.$id);
}
```

Comment: hii. i tried your code but its not working because id represent index of item like (0,1,2,3) but in my case i need to pass -J48go0dwY5M3jAC34Op this string after url then only i can able to delete particular json object. so can you tell me how to get this string ?

Comment: I added a second sample that directly gets at the id. Give that a shot.

Comment: Thanks dear, its working.. :)

can you suggest me good tutorial to learn angular-firebase?

Comment: sadly, no. I've been going the trial and error route. I now see the top example I gave is for using angularFire() and the bottom for angularFireCollection(). In the angularFireCollection case, list.remove(item) also works.

Comment: ohh, is it. anyway o.$id is working totally perfect. it also help me to update json object. may i have ur twitter or gplus id?

Comment: oh gr8. any article on List. if yes plz frwd me link .. thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38233/discussion-between-jaydipsinh-and-jeff-ilse)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a firebaseArray, you can also do it this way:

```
$scope.deleteItem = function(item){
 employee.$remove(item);
}
```

Just pass the item you want to remove from the object.

Note: It won't work for firebaseObjects.

Useful sources:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-removerecordorindex

https://gist.github.com/anantn/4325082